# Windows 10 Bash using "Shutter": Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: at /usr/lib/perl5/Gtk2.pm line 138

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-10-v1607, shutter

Recently installed the developer Bash console in Windows 10 Anniversary update. Tried to install "shutter" with apt-get, and when I try to run it I get this error:

> **Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:  at /usr/lib/perl5/Gtk2.pm line 138.**

Line 138 in this file is

> **Gtk2->init if ($init);**

I'm not versed in Perl at this point, so I'm not sure how I can go about troubleshooting this. I would imagine that my monitor device is not mapped/mounted correctly within this Linux filesystem, and therefore I see this error?